# Maker is not showing in google map

Tags: android, google-maps

Hello everyone i have gone through all the solutions of stackoverflow but cann't find solution among them.I am not able to see the marker in map.All the free main file's content i have written below.
Here is my Main Activity:-

```
public class MainActivityextends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(22.7595, 75.9187);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Vijay Nagar"));
       // mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }
}

Xml File:-
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    tools:context=".MapsActivity"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

Manifest File:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.lalit.maptest" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyA8apU-Fh7PxM9HIL27N8bqzdfpeZaPujQ"/>


    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Remove comments from `mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));`. You will see marker as map animates at marker position.

Comment: is you map ready being called ?

Comment: yes the method is getting called

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```
if (googleMap !=null){
  Marker sydney = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(22.7595, 75.9187))
  .title("Vijay Nagar"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Where the marker should be located? Did you try to zoom out to the whole world? You have created a marker in 22,75 (lat,LNG) and called Sidney, but Sidney is in southern part of the world so lng should be negative. Remember that lat is the y(vertical) and lng is x(horizontal) the 0,0 point is at the center of the map, about somewhere west of Africa. 22,75 is (not checked, just thinking) somewhere in India?